# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib64 when building opencv 4.6 on WSL2

Tags: opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to compile the opencv 4.6 with Cuda 11.7 and Cudnn 8.4.1 on WSL2 with ubuntu 20.04.

I have configured the cmake successfully by following command:

```
cmake \
-D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=ON \
-D WITH_TBB=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D CUDA_ARCH_BIN=7.5 \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=$HOME/source/opencv_contrib/modules \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON \
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64 \
-D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include \
..
```

But when I start to build, it comes out the error:

```
$ make
.
.
.

[  3%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_cudev.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llib64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [modules/cudev/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/build.make:86: lib/libopencv_cudev.so.4.6.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4468: modules/cudev/CMakeFiles/opencv_cudev.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

any ideas?

Comment: `-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64`  -- this should point to a file inside the lib64 folder, not the folder itself

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: @berak you are right, it should be pointed to /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so