# link a shared library to another

Tags: cmake

I am using Cmake as below:

```
**build.sh**

cmake -S . -B $BUILD_DIR_PREFIX$BUILD_TYPE \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=$C_COMPILER \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=$CXX_COMPILER \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE \
-GNinja \
-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES="-lcurl -lssl -lmylib" \
 $SANITIZER \
${CMAKE_PARAMS[@]}
```

I have created a shared library mylib.so in path /home/sama/mylib.so
how can I link my shared library as curl or ssl?
I have done `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/sama/` before but still i get error `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmylib`

Comment: More information about the error, please. Do you got the error during the configuration (`cmake` run)? Or do you got it during the building (when run ninja)? Provide **complete** error message, so it will include information which file is currently linked.

Comment: The error occures in building, And as my shared library is not a standard library how can I link it? using DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES?

Comment: Please, provide **complete** error message, which looks like the one in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73200982/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-llib64-when-building-opencv-4-6-on-wsl2). Note, that variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` is intended for platform-specific libraries needed for any executable on the given platform. For link other libraries, specify them in the `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev if CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES is not usable for other shared libraries which option should be used for not platform-specific libraries and the one that I have created? I can not use CMAkeLists.txt I have to use bash .

Comment: "I can not use CMAkeLists.txt" - Why you cannot modify `CMakeLists.txt`? Linking an executable with a library is useful only when the executable **uses** some **function** from that library. But if a project creates an executable which uses a functions from the library, then it is **responsibility of the project** (and its author) to link with that library. As for `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` variable, it is **compiler** which generates calls to functions defined in that libraries. Since a CMake project doesn't specify a compiler, it cannot predict which libraries should be linked.

Comment: It seems you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But you neither provide addition details nor provide complete error message, as I asked you. How should we help you with that?